# About Group Isomorphism Kernel

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

It's clear to me that a group homomorphism kernel measures how much the homomorphism is close to be an isomorphism, i.e. if this kernel contains more than the identity, the homomorphism cannot be injective, and so cannot lead to any isomorphism at all.

This sounds to me a "necessary" condition, so far so good.

I was wondering whether this is a "sufficient" condition as well, i.e. whether to check a kernel being made by the identity only it's ENOUGH to claim the homomorphism is actually a isomorphism.

Please, give some counter examples in negative case.
Tx in advance.

Comment: See also: is every injection a bijection?

Comment: Since the surjectivity depends of a map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ depends on the space $Y$, you cannot check the bijectivity only by studying the kernel. You must add conditions on $Y$ (e.g. if $X$ and $Y$ are finite groups of the same order) to get the implication "injective $\Rightarrow$ bijective".

Comment: Consider any nontrivial group $G$ and the unique map $\{1_G\} \to G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel being trivial is equivalent to the homomorphism being injective, but it may still fail to be bijective if it is not surjective. Take $C_2\to C_4\colon a\mapsto b^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are generators of the cyclic groups $C_2$ and $C_4$ respectively.

What you can say is that, given a homomorphism $f\colon G\to H$, then the kernel of $f$ is trivial if and only if $f$ defines an isomorphism between $G$ and its image $f(G)$, a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Why this has been downvoted twice?

Comment: I'd love to know....

Comment: So this what I thought as well. If it's a isomophism the kernel Is trivial but not the opposite. So the kernel triviality Is a necessary condition only. I think this emerges also from the First isomorphism thm, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you disagree with the downvotes, feel free to vote accordingly. The other answers to this question have also been receiving spurious down votes which I cannot understand, either

Answer (score 2):

For finite groups since $f$ is injective if and only if $Kerf=\{0\}$. If We have $f : G\to H$ with $ord(G) =ord(H) $, f is isomorphism if and only if the kernel is trivial. For infinite groups that's not true, for example $f : (\mathbb{Z},+) \to (\mathbb{Z}, +), \quad x\mapsto 2x$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varphi : G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism.

Then $\ker(\varphi) $ measure how far a homorphism to be an injective map.

Injectivity alone isn't enough to ensure whether the homomorphism is an isomorphism Or not.

Example : $ \varphi: S_n \to GL_n(\Bbb{Z}) $ defined by $\varphi(\pi) =P_{\pi}$ where $P_{\pi}=(e_{\pi(1)},e_{\pi(2)}, \ldots e_{\pi(n)})$ and $e_j$ is the $j-$th standard basis vector (column) .

Then $\ker(\varphi)=\{(1)\}$ but $\varphi$ isn't an isomorphism.Find $\varphi(S_n) $ ?

A injective homomorphism $\varphi : G\to G'$  is an isomorphism iff $\varphi(G) $ is an improper subgroup of $G'$  iff $\varphi$ is onto.

Comment: $|\varphi(G)|=|G'|$ is only equivalent if these are finite groups - see the other answers and comments to this question.

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Take the example in @guillerminho77's answer: $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}:x\mapsto 2x$. The image is $2\mathbb{Z}<\mathbb{Z}$ which is a proper subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as an abstract group, but $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism. In this case $|2\mathbb{Z}|=|\varphi(\mathbb{Z})|=|\mathbb{Z}|=\aleph_0$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.I will remove this.

Comment: the phrase "improper subgroup" gave me pause. You're saying it's **not** a **non**trivial subgroup :D

Comment: $H\le G$ is improper if $H$ is not a proper subset of $G$ .In other words $H=G$